# Using a table-value function inside a view in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

I have a table-value function that works correctly if I try the following query:

```
SELECT    *
FROM    dbo.GetScheduleForEmployee() AS schedule
```

However if I try to create a view with that query I get a "too few parameters" error.

Is there a limitation with table-value functions and views?

Comment: Show us your function and how you define your view!!

Comment: The problem only happens within the query designer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetScheduleForEmployee()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
        RETURN
        (
        SELECT  1 AS id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2
        )
GO

CREATE VIEW myview
AS
SELECT  *
FROM    GetScheduleForEmployee() AS schedule

GO

SELECT  *
FROM    myview
```

Comment: i just realized that the problem only happens when using the query designer to create the view

Comment: If you are using MySQL you should take note that query designer will only execute the first line/statement of whatever you put in there.

Comment: Thanks rlb.usa i'm using SQL Server (as specified in title and question tags),