# Problem building view where underling tables may not have all expected values

Tags: sql, sql-server

My problem is I am trying to build a view of 3 tables, tables1 and table2 have one entry / row per table for each document in the system guaranteed, and table3 will have up to 5 entry / rows but may have less.

My current SQL code works only if all expected entry / rows are there, if a document only has four entry’s in teble3 no row is created in the view.

I would like the have a row in the table will NULL where no record was found.

```
SELECT M.DocumentID, 
    M.ProjectID, 
    DOC.CurrentStatusID, 
    Vv0.ValueText AS vDocNumber,
    Vv1.ValueText AS vTitle1,
    Vv2.ValueText AS vTitle2,
    Vv3.ValueText AS vTitle3,
    Vv4.ValueText AS vProjectNumber,
Vv5.ValueText AS vRevision
        
FROM [JDS01].[dbo].[DocumentsInProjects] M
INNER JOIN [JDS01].[dbo].[Documents] AS DOC ON M.DocumentID = DOC.DocumentID
LEFT JOIN [JDS01].[dbo].VariableValue AS Vv0 ON M.DocumentID = Vv0.DocumentID
LEFT JOIN [JDS01].[dbo].VariableValue AS Vv1 ON M.DocumentID = Vv1.DocumentID
LEFT JOIN [JDS01].[dbo].VariableValue AS Vv2 ON M.DocumentID = Vv2.DocumentID
LEFT JOIN [JDS01].[dbo].VariableValue AS Vv3 ON M.DocumentID = Vv3.DocumentID
LEFT JOIN [JDS01].[dbo].VariableValue AS Vv4 ON M.DocumentID = Vv4.DocumentID
LEFT JOIN [JDS01].[dbo].VariableValue AS Vv5 ON M.DocumentID = Vv5.DocumentID 

WHERE M.Deleted = 0

AND Vv0.VariableID = 1061
AND Vv0.ConfigurationID = 2
AND Vv0.RevisionNo = (SELECT MAX(xx.RevisionNo) FROM [JDS01].[dbo].[VariableValue] AS xx
                    WHERE Vv0.DocumentID = xx.DocumentID
                    AND xx.ConfigurationID = 2
                    AND xx.VariableID = 1061)

AND Vv1.VariableID = 50
AND Vv1.ConfigurationID = 2
AND Vv1.RevisionNo = (SELECT MAX(xx.RevisionNo) FROM [JDS01].[dbo].[VariableValue] AS xx
                    WHERE Vv1.DocumentID = xx.DocumentID
                    AND xx.ConfigurationID = 2
                    AND xx.VariableID = 50)
AND Vv2.VariableID = 51
AND Vv2.ConfigurationID = 2
AND Vv2.RevisionNo = (SELECT MAX(xx.RevisionNo) FROM [JDS01].[dbo].[VariableValue] AS xx
                    WHERE Vv2.DocumentID = xx.DocumentID
                    AND xx.ConfigurationID = 2
                    AND xx.VariableID = 51)
AND Vv3.VariableID = 52
AND Vv3.ConfigurationID = 2
AND Vv3.RevisionNo = (SELECT MAX(xx.RevisionNo) FROM [JDS01].[dbo].[VariableValue] AS xx
                    WHERE Vv3.DocumentID = xx.DocumentID
                    AND xx.ConfigurationID = 2
                    AND xx.VariableID = 52)
AND Vv4.VariableID = 48
AND Vv4.ConfigurationID = 2
AND Vv4.RevisionNo = (SELECT MAX(xx.RevisionNo) FROM [JDS01].[dbo].[VariableValue] AS xx
                    WHERE Vv4.DocumentID = xx.DocumentID
                    AND xx.ConfigurationID = 2
                    AND xx.VariableID = 48)

  AND Vv5.VariableID = 1054
  AND Vv5.ConfigurationID = 2
  AND Vv5.RevisionNo = (SELECT MAX(xx.RevisionNo) FROM [JDS01].[dbo].[VariableValue] AS xx
                    WHERE Vv5.DocumentID = xx.DocumentID
                    AND xx.ConfigurationID = 2
                    AND xx.VariableID = 1054)
```

Comment: You need to move the filtering conditions on all but the first table to the `on` clauses.

Comment: This query feels like it would be better served as a `PIVOT`/Cross Tab.

Comment: The SQL you have here looks very bad. Why don't you create a nice function and generate your view based on the returned values. Example of view from function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877247/using-a-table-value-function-inside-a-view-in-sql-server

Comment: And one last suggestion - don't use 3 part names without a very good reason. This tends to make your code more difficult to use in different environments (and makes setting up those environments vastly more difficult and time-consuming). Your connection should determine which database to use for your object references.

Comment: Thanks All, Gordon Can you give me an example of the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Gordon's answer (which I believe is correct), move the AND conditions out of the WHERE clause to be part of the associated ON conditions for each of the LEFT JOINs e.g.:

```
LEFT JOIN [JDS01].[dbo].VariableValue AS Vv0 ON M.DocumentID = Vv0.DocumentID
      AND Vv0.VariableID = 1061
      AND Vv0.ConfigurationID = 2
      AND Vv0.RevisionNo = (SELECT MAX(xx.RevisionNo) FROM [JDS01].[dbo].[VariableValue] AS xx
                WHERE Vv0.DocumentID = xx.DocumentID
                AND xx.ConfigurationID = 2
                AND xx.VariableID = 1061)
```

Putting the condition in the WHERE clause will remove the row from the result set altogether if there's no associated entry, while placing the condition in the ON clause of the LEFT JOIN will permit a row to be returned with NULL values.